# Valid filenames for add_action's first parameter

Tags: plugin-development, filters, actions

Some examples in WordPress' docs pass a filename to `add_action` rather than an action name. For example,

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'callback' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'callback' );
```

What are the valid filenames for the first argument in `add_action`?

Comment: Just found my answer. Those aren't filenames but examples of the load-\[filename.php\] action. Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page)

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough to do it immediately; have to wait an hour from the post time. :) Update: Actually I have to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my answer. Those aren't filenames but examples of the [`load-(page)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) action.